# Anime about a guy that goes to a magic school but doesn't have any magic

Tags: story-identification, anime

Got told of an anime about a guy that goes to a magic school but doesn't have any magic. Heard he had black gloves and some students don't want to let him in because he doesn't have magic so he fights them.

Got told the guy is holding a girl at one point and she says he's not gonna hit a girl and hits one coming at him from the back. He doesn't use any type of magic at all.

Can anyone please tell me the name?

Comment: Can you [edit](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/posts/194723/edit) your question with any additional info like side characters, use of weapons or not, type like romance or comedy or action, any more detail about storyline or even when the anime was aired? In anime there are a number (okay a lot) of weak but not really due to 'hidden power' protagonists so other details like costumes, powers, events helps in identifying.

Comment: Honorable mention: In a way this fits [Rock Lee](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rock_Lee) of the Naruto Shipuuden manga and anime: in a village and world of magical ninjas who can shape-change, channel demons, control the elements, manipulate people's minds, give shadows substance and direct them against their foes, etc. Rock is a muggle. So he pushes his physical martial arts training to extremes. His gloves (more wrappings) are white, not black though, and there's a secret which is revealed at one point when he unwraps them. And of course he is *always* fighting magical ninjas. :)

Answer (score 6):

This may be ***The Irregular at Magic High School***.  From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Irregular_at_Magic_High_School):

> The story takes place in an alternate history where magic exists and
>   is polished through modern technology. It follows Tatsuya and Miyuki
>   Shiba, siblings who enroll into **First High magic high school**. While
>   keeping their connections to the infamous Yotsuba clan secret, they
>   attempt to live their daily life in peace where **Tatsuya is shunned for
>   his apparent ineptness** and Miyuki is validated for her magical
>   abilities.

He does not wear gloves that I recall, but the first episode involves other students picking a fight with him (and, predictably, losing; there is more to him than meets the eye).

One of the large themes of the show is that the students are segregated into first course (magically proficient) and second course (magically deficient), and that there is much friction between the two groups ("blooms" and "weeds").  This is reflected in the image below, where Miyuke bears a blossom emblem in a rectangle on her uniform's upper arm, whereas Tatsuya's upper arm has an empty rectangle instead.

[image: The Irregular at Magic High School]

Comment: Thanks but that isnt it. Got told the guy is holding a girl at one point and she says he's not gonna hit a girl and hits one coming at him from the back. He doesnt use any type of magic at all. ( but that one looks good tbh)

Comment: @Christopher Well, come on, it's anime, he probably gets powers sooner or later :) Finds out his grandfather was the wizardest of all wizards. Or someone messes with his sexual tension love interest, and he goes into power-unlock rage mode and sets everything on fire.

Comment: In this show, the character that would most fit the bill still uses magic, he just uses incredibly powerful magic that limits his ability to perform more mundane magic which most of the other high school students are using at their experience level. This doesn't fit OP's description, if OP's description is accurate. Also all the students in this school have to be capable of magic... at least insofar as magic exists in that world.

Comment: Gonna be honest all those anime look great. Saw the irregular and was great. But thats all the info i got told and the bastard didnt even know the name so i've been searching for it

Comment: The hero of this series can still use magic just not the types that are typically considered to be magic.

Answer (score 4):

It could be *[Aesthetica of a Rogue Hero](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aesthetica_of_a_Rogue_Hero)*.  The main character Osawa Akatsuki is a returnee from an alternate world.  It turns out this happens a lot in Japan, so those teenagers are sent to a special school to help them hone and expand the magic they learned in another world (and so the government can use and keep an eye on them).  Except Akatsuki has no magic, his powers are based on martial arts, ki, and sexual harassment (yes, it's that kind of show).  He never hits a girl, but is not above stripping them naked.

In the first few episodes, he gets attacked by multiple other students for various reasons.

He frequently ends up holding girls:
[image]

And his combat suit has fingerless black gloves:
[image]

Answer (score 2):

That sounds like [Armed Girl's Machiavellism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Armed_Girl%27s_Machiavellism). The description of the main character matches perfectly, even down to the black gloves

> Fudo Nomura is a young man who was recently expelled from his old high school as a result of a massive, violent brawl. He wants a normal life, but the new school he transferred to is Private Aichi Symbiosis Academy, where the female students have been violently oppressing their male classmates out of misguided paranoia ever since the school became co-ed. A five-member vigilante group called the "Supreme Five Swords" led by Rin Onigawara holds Nomura at sword-point to concede to the rules or leave the school. At this point, Nomura challenges the Supreme Five Swords for his own right and prove true morality despite the brutal force.

You should check it out for yourself as I haven't watched it in a really long time. It is a good series though.

Comment: I've taken the liberty of adding in a blurb and the trailer.Something visual in your answer would definitely be helpful in ID-ing it.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like the anime called *[Mx0](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%C3%970)*.

[image: Front cover of *Mx0*]

During a flashback, an interviewer inquires Kuzumi Taiga, a prospective student for Seinagi Private High School, on what he would do if he could use magic, during his entrance interview. He replies, "take over the world", with an outburst of laughter, from an attractive girl, following his answer. After the entrance exam, the school rejects his application; although he recalls almost nothing after this event, he does recall the girl, and believes the cause of his school of choice rejecting his application involves her. Wandering around outside of the school the next day, Kuzumi tries to enter, but an invisible barrier blocks him. A teacher, Mr. Hiiragi, confuses Kuzumi for a student of the school ditching class and pulls Kuzumi into the school through the barrier. Seinagi Private High School is actually a magic school and Kuzumi is a teenager with no magical skill.

> Taiga is the protagonist of the story who is a normal guy who fails at first to get into the high school of his choice, but is soon after taken into the school grounds against his will when he is mistaken for a truant student. He tends to have a very strong-willed personality and never wants to back down from anything. His personality is only matched by his physical strength, as he extremely skilled in hand-to-hand combat which is a result of his sister practicing on him constantly. At his preliminary interview into the school of magic he attends, he met a girl named Aika Hiiragi, who he instantly has feelings towards. Once admitted to the school, he quickly finds out that he will not be learning any magic for the time being until they can issue him a proper magic plate, a sort of magical data storage device, which allows for magical spells and power to be stored. As it is, ever since he was admitted to the school, he has wished he could use magic someday. While he is unable to use magic, much of the school believes his magic skills are far superior to any normal freshman, which makes him very popular.
>
> During an incident with school bullies who stole plates from students, Taiga lost his temporary plate. He faced either expulsion, or to make a wish, as all students who graduated from the magic school are allowed a wish in proportion to the amount of magical power they have acquired. Depending on the wish the principal was to judge if Taiga would be allowed to remain in the school as losing a plate was a serious offense. Taiga's wish was so that he could "Grant someone else's wish if that person isn't able to grant that wish on their own." The person in question was Aika, who in a chat revealed that her mother died while she was still young, and her greatest wish would be to see her. The principal had a lie-discovering spell cast on herself so she would be able to see if Taiga answered truthfully, which he did. The principal was content and granted him his own personal plate, The M0.

Comment: A source to back up your evidence would be good, but well-written answer.

Answer (score 1):

*[Chivalry of a Failed Knight](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chivalry_of_a_Failed_Knight)*

[image: Cover image of *Chivalry of a Failed Knight*]

> The story is set in an Alternate Earth world where humans called "Blazers" have supernatural abilities. These Blazers can materialize weapons known as "Device" which are made through a person's soul. At Hagun Academy (破軍学園, Hagun Gakuen), Blazers are selected as representatives for the Seven Star Sword Art Festival, an annual tournament event held by the seven Mage Knight Academies in Japan to determine the strongest Apprentice Knight. Hagun's performance ranking in the festival is falling and academy director Kurono Shinguji is determined to find a solution. Ikki Kurogane is the academy's F-Rank Blazer and is considered "The Worst One" for his low magical abilities, but Stella Vermillion, the princess of the European country Vermillion, is one of the top A-Rank Blazers.
>
> On Stella's first day at Hagun, she is arranged to share a room with Ikki as a transfer student of the academy. When Ikki inadvertently discovers Stella half-dressed, he is challenged to duel where the loser has to be obedient to the winner for life. She ends up losing the duel, but they agree to become roommates. The series follows their adventures as they train to qualify as the school's representatives for the festival.

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure the anime you're looking for is Akashic Records of Bastard Magic

Here's the clip that was surfacing through social media:

Or konosuba

Comment: Given the main character is most definitely a magic user, and is a teacher not a student, it doesn't seem to fit the primary criteria.

Answer (score 1):

*Black Clover*. Asta doesn't have any magic even though everyone else does. So he has to rely on his physical. I remembered because he wanted to be Wizard King. I looked up Wizard King and found it.

Answer (score -2):

[Mashle: Magic and Muscles](https://www.viz.com/shonenjump/chapters/mashle) is probably the one you want. [MangaDex](https://mangadex.org/title/44976/mashle-magic-and-muscles) describes the story as:

> This is a world of magic where magic is used for everything. But deep
> in the forest exists a young man who spends his time training and
> bulking up. He can't use magic, but he enjoys a peaceful life with his
> father. But one day, his life is put in danger! Will his muscular body
> protect him from the magic users who are out to get him? Powerfully
> trained muscles crush magic as this abnormal magical fantasy begins!

Comment: Hi welcome to SF&F.  Please add details about this work and how it matches the question.

Comment: The question was asked in 2018.  The Mashle manga started in 2020.  There is no way this is the answer.