# Anime in which the main character has no magic power but goes to a magic school

Tags: story-identification, anime, magic

So this is true for a lot of anime. I am searching for a specific one. The main character is a real life illusionist (ala David Blaine, David Copperfield or Hans Klok). He is admitted to a magic school and needs to convince everyone he has magic with his magic tricks. i am certain it is more of a slice of life anime than a fighting anime. Picture Harry Potter universe but with a muggle attending Hogwarts that can only do magic tricks.

Comment: A liar At Magic High School? https://myanimelist.net/anime/20785/Mahouka_Koukou_no_Rettousei

Comment: This is a pretty common trope. You could improve this question by going through the checklists [here](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11874/how-to-ask-a-good-anime-manga-story-id-question) and editing in any relevant info you can think to add.

Comment: Possibly one of these; [Anime about a guy that goes to a magic school but doesn't have any magic](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/194723/anime-about-a-guy-that-goes-to-a-magic-school-but-doesnt-have-any-magic)

Comment: Thanks for your help, unfortunately that is not it. I only heard about this from someone I can't contact anymore. I have no further information

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Little_Witch_Academia?

Comment: The TV Tropes page where it should appear: https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/FakeWizardry unfortunately doesn't seem to have the series you're looking for.

Answer (score -2):

[*Mashle: Magic and Muscles*](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Manga/MashleMagicAndMuscles)

> This is a world of magic where magic is used for everything. But deep in the forest exists a young man who spends his time training and bulking up. He can't use magic, but he enjoys a peaceful life with his father. But one day, his life is put in danger! Will his muscular body protect him from the magic users who are out to get him? Powerfully trained muscles crush magic as this abnormal magical fantasy begins!

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Does the protagonist go to magic school?  Is he an illusionist?

Comment: This doesn't seem to match; while the protagonist attends a Not-Hogwarts school (complete with a Not-Dumbledore headmaster and a Not-Quidditch sport on flying broomsticks), his characteristic is being extremely fit and overcoming every magical obstacle using his strength and athleticism. In the 9 episodes aired to this date there are no instances of "tricks".

Comment: The anime also didn't air until half a year after the question was asked.